# Trimming not responding correctly

Tags: jquery

Alright so I've got a lil bit of a problem here, I am trying to submit a normal form but its not checking correctly if the field is empty or not. Whatever happens (empty or not empty) it will ignore the trim check.

HTML

```
    <label>Your IG-Name</label><br/><input id="Username" type="text" name="veh_IGUsername" autocomplete='off'/><br/><br/>
<input id="form_send" type="submit" name="veh_Submit" value="Send"/>
```

And the Jquery

```
$("#form_send").click(function() {
        var username = $.trim($("#Username").val());
        if(username.lenght <= 0) { alert("Please insert your in game username. This field cannot be empty"); return false; }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: you spelled length wrong. `username.lenght`

Comment: oh wow.. thanks mate, didnt even notice that one

Answer (score 0):

Spelling of`length` is incorrect. Check in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/9k5bs7j8/#&togetherjs=9yGa4MkqUV)

```
$("#form_send").click(function() {
        var username = $.trim($("#Username").val());
        //alert(username);
        if(username.length <= 0) { alert("Please insert your in game username. This field cannot be empty"); return false; }
        return false;
    });
```